# Gridsearch for NLP - How to combine CountVec and other features?

Tags: python, nlp, pipeline, modeling

I am doing a basic NLP project on Sentiment Analysis, and I would like to use GridsearchCV to optimise my model.

The code below shows a sample dataframe I am working with. 'Content' is the column to pass to CountVectorizer, 'label' is the y column to be predicted, and feature_1, feature_2 are columns I wish to include in my model as well.

```
'content': 'Got flat way today Pot hole Another thing tick crap thing happen week list',
'feature_1': '1', 
'feature_2': '34', 
'label':1}, 
{'content': 'UP today Why doe head hurt badly',
'feature_1': '5', 
'feature_2': '142', 
'label':1},
{'content': 'spray tan fail leg foot Ive scrubbing foot look better ',
 'feature_1': '7', 
'feature_2': '123', 
'label':0},])
```

I am following a stackoverflow answer: [Perform feature selection using pipeline and gridsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841913/perform-feature-selection-using-pipeline-and-gridsearch)

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
class CustomFeatureExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, feature_1=True, feature_2=True):
        self.feature_1=feature_1
        self.feature_2=feature_2
        
    def extractor(self, tweet):
        features = []

        if self.feature_2:
            
            features.append(df['feature_2'])

        if self.feature_1:
            features.append(df['feature_1'])
        
          
        return np.array(features)

    def fit(self, raw_docs, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, raw_docs):
        
        return np.vstack(tuple([self.extractor(tweet) for tweet in raw_docs]))
```

Below is the gridsearch I tried to fit my dataframe on:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()

# Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('features', FeatureUnion([("vectorizer", CountVectorizer(df['content'])),
                                            ("extractor", CustomFeatureExtractor())]))
                 ,('classifier', lr())
                ])
But yields results: TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable
```

Wonder if there are any other easier ways to do this?

I have already referred to the threads below, however, to no avail:
[How to combine TFIDF features with other features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573174/how-to-combine-tfidf-features-with-other-features)
[Perform feature selection using pipeline and gridsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841913/perform-feature-selection-using-pipeline-and-gridsearch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do `lr()`, `LogisticRegression` is not callable indeed, it has some methods for the `lr` object.

Try instead (`lr` without brackets):

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
pipe = Pipeline([('features', FeatureUnion([("vectorizer", CountVectorizer(df['content'])),
                                            ("extractor", CustomFeatureExtractor())]))
                 ,('classifier', lr)
                ])
```

and your error message should disappear.